# Error installing Docker `https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal Release 404 Not Found`

Tags: linux, docker

I'm following [these](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) instructions to install Docker.

When I reach this command: 
`sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"`

I get the following error

`Err:11 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2600:9000:2177:b200:3:db06:4200:93a1 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given `focal` in the error message, I believe you are using Ubuntu 20.04 pre-release build. For that release, package is not available here https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/ yet.

Comment: Is that what `focal` means?

Comment: Ubuntu releases have names associated to them, the command you mentioned in post `lsb_release -cs` will print the name of the release you have installed.

Comment: Ahhh makes perfect sense now. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, I understood why I got stuck. But now what to do, in order to install docker?